# Chrome Extension Browser Action does nothing when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've searched through stackoverflow and google's extension FAQ but could not seem to find the answer. Browser actions for my chrome extension refuse to work... Here is my code. Note: i've tried using background.html instead of .js - no go. It never calls linker.js.

Manifest.json

```
{

    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": "background.js",      
    "description": "test",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
   "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test",
        "default_icon": "raindrop.png"
        }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "linker.js"});
});
```

linker.js

```
alert("linker is running");

plus more code here
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest needs to be `"background_page": "background.html"`. Within `background.html` you need to include `<script src="background.js"></script>`. This will add the `onClicked` listener and it looks like `linker.js` should trigger an alert.

Comment: I ended up changing the manifest to `"background_page": "background.html"` and I just put the contents of background.js into the background.html file, with the `<script> tags.

Reloaded the extension, and clicking on the icon still doesn't generate an alert message. What else could be wrong?

Comment: At this point you need to do some step by step debugging. If you put an `alert` inside a `<script/>` tag in `background.html` does it trigger? The next step to try would be adding an `alert` just inside `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener.

Comment: I ended up putting the script in a background.js, and calling background.js from background.html. When I put in an alert in background.html, it works. When I put it in background.js, before the chrome.browserAction.onClicked, it works. How do I put it just inside the onclicked listener? I have `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {code:"alert(\"test\""});
});` and that doesn't work.

Comment: Is this right? `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(alert("test"));
`

When I do that, it gives me the alert right when I reload the extension, but not when I actually click on it.

Comment: With the changes to background.html as suggested by user1137778 your code works unless your on a chrome page like the NTP or a web app...which makes sense as your not allowed to affect them.  Try going to google or something and clicking your browser action.

Comment: i made the changes, reloaded, went to google and still not working. latest version of chrome 16.0.912.75

Comment: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { alert("test"); });`

Comment: ^That works as well. But when I put the alert in the executeScript function, it doesn't work. How can I fix this? My exact code is: `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"alert(\"test\""});
});`

Comment: I just tested the `executeScript` and it worked for me. Open chrome://extensions/, enable developer mode, expand the detailed view for your extension, click on `background.html` to open the web inspector and try it again. There should be an error message.

Comment: I've done that, and no error shows up when I click my icon when I'm on a regular page like google.com. When I'm on the Google Extension page, it gives me an error during tabs.executescript, which is expected b/c scripts aren't allowed to run on that page. So we know the inspector is working and Chrome is attempting to run the executescript function...it just doesn't do anything or output any errors!

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. It sounds like everything should be working. Maybe if you reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce and post it somewhere so we can look at it.

Answer (score -1):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"alert('test!')"});
});
```